# Reduce loading time jqwidgets autocomple select

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqwidget

This project is in angular. I am using jqwidgets autocomple select.here is my js code.

```
  var source =
    {
        datatype: "json",
        localdata: Employees,
        datafields: [
                    { name: 'EmployeeID' },
                    { name: 'EmployeeName' }
                ]
    };

var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

//if (document.getElementById("#jqxEmployee") != undefined) {
try {
    $("#jqxEmployeeid").jqxComboBox({ source: dataAdapter, displayMember: "EmployeeName", valueMember: "EmployeeID", multiSelect: false, width: '100%', height: 30 });
    // trigger selection changes.

    $("#jqxEmployeeid").on('change', function (event) {
        var items = $("#jqxEmployeeid").jqxComboBox('getSelectedItems');
        var selectedItems = "Selected Items: ";
        $.each(items, function (index) {
            //////debugger;
            selectedItems += this.label;
            if (items.length - 1 != index) {
                selectedItems += ", ";
            }
        });
        //$("#log").text(selectedItems);
    });
}
catch (exce) {

}
```

my csttml code is

```
<div id='jqxEmployeeid' onkeypress="javascript:return isAlphabet(event)" ng-paste='preventPaste($event)'
                                    ng-keyup="clearvalue()">
                                </div>
```

It is working fine.but local data Employees have around 4000 values.that is why it is affecting my page load time.my page loading take about  45 sec.Is there any method available for reduce loading time.or there is any alternative which can be used which is more effective.

PS:I have used  remote Autocomplete in jqwidget but it is not working after typing 2 words it gets disable.it is loading data but it dont have autocomplete effect plus UI is disaster.for reference remote autocomplete code is

```
  var source =
    {
        datatype: "json",
        localdata: Employees,
        datafields: [
                    { name: 'EmployeeID' },
                    { name: 'EmployeeName' }
                ]
    };
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source,
            {
                formatData: function (data) {
                    if ($("#jqxEmployeeid").jqxComboBox('searchString') != undefined) {
                        data.name_startsWith = $("#jqxEmployeeid").jqxComboBox('searchString');
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }
        );

//  var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
$("#jqxEmployeeid").jqxComboBox(
        {

            width: '100%',
            height: 30,
            source: dataAdapter,
            remoteAutoComplete: true,
            autoDropDownHeight: true,
            selectedIndex: 0,
            displayMember: "EmployeeName",
            valueMember: "EmployeeID",
            renderer: function (index, label, value) {

                var item = dataAdapter.records[index];
                if (item != null) {
                    var label = item.EmployeeName;
                    return label;
                }
                return "";
            },
            renderSelectedItem: function (index, item) {
                var item = dataAdapter.records[index];
                if (item != null) {
                    var label = item.name;
                    return label;
                }
                return "";
            },
            search: function (searchString) {
                dataAdapter.dataBind();
            }
        });
```

my json data

```
{"FetchEmployeeResult":[{"Email":"Ahfdgdfg.com","EmployeeID":"36","EmployeeName":" dfsdfdsfdd"},{"Email":"dfgfdghdf.com","EmployeeID":"37","EmployeeName":"ghdfghdfhdf"}]});
```

Comment: please can anybody give any idea

Comment: Why do you use the jQuery way to create your widgets rather than create them using the way forseen for the usage of jqWidgets with angular? As far as the 45s loading time is concerned: How is your data loaded? What takes that much time? For the widgets, 4000 values is not a problem.